# how to install Tkinter to Pycharm(community edition)?

Tags: python, gui, pycharm

It gives me error when i run my "Tkinter" code.It says "Tk() was not defined". I tried to download Tkinter on PyCharm but there are a lot of them. Well, I don't know what to do. Help please.

Comment: Just install `python-tk` via your system's package manager for the version of Python that you are using.

Comment: You should also check that Pycharm can see it by checking the package manager from within Pycharm, as explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html).

Answer (score 0):

Install future instead of Tkinter on Pycharm. In the Pycharm console, install future as

```
pip install future
```

after install is done, use below to import Tkinter

```
from future.moves import tkinter
```